# Mixed content google chrome PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome, http, https, internet-radio

I have a problem with including radio station into my website. My website use https and the streaming server use http, the player I am generating from http://wavestreaming.com/player/free-shoutcast-flash-player-generator use http protocol. So when trying to insert the player into my radio, it gives me mixed content error in google chrome, any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using HTTPS on your web site, presumably to give the end user some kind of protection against eavesdropping as well as some certification of who sent the content. Not only is inserting HTTP data (not encrypted) into the exact same page misleading to the end user (graphically it indicates the whole page is secure but it obviously is not), it also gives the third party (wavestreaming) information about your visitors.

I would question your need for HTTPS in the first place, and if you do need it for some reason on your site, you should be honest towards your end users and put the radio on a separate page that is not secured, or link them to wavestreaming directly. The mixed content warning is there for a reason, and you shouldn't bypass it.

Comment: How to connect them to wavestreaming directly??

Comment: Instead of embedding wavestreaming, give the visitor an external link to that site.